# Call custom function before print value in <struts-tags:text /> in java

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using struts-tags for I18 & I am using <s:text name="" /> tag for render internationalization language from .properties file.

I want to call custom function before it render value to JSP page.

Is there any option available for same?

By default resourcebundle_ja_JP.properties file is in UTF-8 format.
when I user `<s:text name="user.preferences.label.emailPreferences"/>` line, it read file in non UTF format and that's why I want to manually convert value in UTF-8 format.

I can't use

```
<s:property value = "getText('user.preferences.label.emailPreferences')" />
```

as the project is very huge & there are too many changes so I am finding any method to override using `<s:text name="" />` only.

**JSP page**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<s:text name="user.preferences.label.emailPreferences"/>
```

**resourcebundle_ja_JP.properties**

```
user.preferences.label.emailPreferences=メールの設定
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<s:text>`, as you note, calls `getText`.

`getText`, IIRC, is in `ActionSupport`.

It's just a method--you can override `getText` as necessary. I'm not 100% sure what your goal is here; I18N resource files can contain UTF-8 resources (e.g., Japanese characters) and it works fine--the problem may be with your resource files or build process.